# Sqlite3: Drop indexes to improve Insert performance, but then Commits are slow

Tags: sql, indexing, sqlite, insert, commit

I have a Python program which processes large amounts of data files and extracts records from them and then inserts them into an SQLITE3 database.
I am partitioning the databases by date (Create a new one for each day) to cut down on size but they still get up to 9GB, and Insert speed gradually becomes slow because the table has an index.

So before adding in a bunch of records I want to drop the index, then add it again after, and the records should insert much faster. However what I have found is the Insert operation speed is improved, but then the Commit after each record batch takes forever!

Here's an example from logs, With Index:

```
DB-ADDREC-START|Adding 11425 records from 2017-05-01 into database...
DB-ADDREC-END| (Duration: 9.15 seconds)
DB-COMMIT-START|Committing database transaction..
DB-COMMIT-END| (Duration: 0.96 seconds)
```

After index removed, commit time is quite variable but gets very large:

```
DB-ADDREC-START|Adding 10681 records from 2017-05-01 into database...
DB-ADDREC-END| (Duration: 0.06 seconds)
DB-COMMIT-START|Committing database transaction..
DB-COMMIT-END| (Duration: 2.29 seconds)

DB-ADDREC-START|Adding 11185 records from 2017-05-01 into database...
DB-ADDREC-END| (Duration: 0.20 seconds)
DB-COMMIT-START|Committing database transaction..
DB-COMMIT-END| (Duration: 21.28 seconds)
```

To help I have also set:

```
PRAGMA synchronous=OFF
```

Also I am currently using WAL journal mode

Why does the commit time become much higher and how can I prevent it?

Comment: In your analogy you are forgetting the purpose of disassembling the bicycle.. a more accurate one would be spending time to transform the bicycle into an effective stair-climbing machine that is an order of magnitude faster than walking up the stairs, then transforming back again.
For a sufficiently large batch job, dropping then re-adding indexes should improve insert performance. Either way this doesn't explain why commit time is longer without indexes, I suspect it has something to do with WAL more or the database file being on NFS

Comment: I don't ride bicycles when writing SQL queries because it's dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

In WAL mode, the database needs to do [checkpoints](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#checkpointing) after a certain amount of changes. (This is independet of whether you have an index or not, but with the index, more data gets changed, so you should see more frequent checkpoints.)

When doing large changes, [disable WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode); this is likely to have a larger effect than disabling the index.

Comment: Ok, I'll experiment with setting journal mode back to default (delete).
However, both cases in my OP are using WAL mode, I still don't see why commit time with no indexes is so much longer. BTW the database files are on a NFS

Comment: If you're using NFS, read http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html, and consider using OFF journal mode (it's fastest).